# The red top bar led to a interface error

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app, I set a audio key in background in the info.plist. Then the app enter to background, the screen will show a red top bar. But when i come back to the app, i find the interface is misplacement. The tabbar have moved down or moved up. How I can resolve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Comment: How are you actually using the navigation bar, from code or from storyboard? Can you paste code/screenshots?